# Projecting Data with Transformations - Alignment Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, alignment

**Problem:**

I am having problems getting data to align properly with basemaps layers.  The image below shows the difference between roads.

The centerlines shapefile's coordinate system is GCS_North_American_1983 while the basemap is WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere.

**Things I have tried:**

I have tried projecting the centerlines shapefile into WGS_84 to get it to better alignment.  I have tried using WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983 and NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5 transformations without much luck. I have tried changing the projection of the data to different ones thinking it may have been wrong at the start.

**Shapefile Info:**

Comparing the data and the basemaps, it looks like there is about a 40 meter difference.  I am assuming this is a projection issue because it is hard to imagine the data being off by that much when it was created.

My data is in western Pennsylvania.  The shapefile's extent is: top 41.892328dd, right -77.075914dd, bottom 39.625013dd, left -80.565890dd.  The basemap is the photo is from ArcMap, but the same issue is there is another program I am using with Google Maps as basemaps.

These shapefiles contain M and Z values, but I am not sure if that would really factor into the alignment.

We are using this data for offline field collection, so it needs to match (more closely) the basemaps we will show it on.  All of the shapefiles I have are off according to the basemaps, too.

[image: My Photo]

Comment: Also asked on [Esri GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/112983).

Comment: What's the imagery source? Has it been properly orthorectified, preferably with ground control points?

Comment: try convert all data to srid:900973 or 3857